# How can I upgrade lxml for python2.6

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, command-line, python-2.6

I am receiving the following error when running a python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/scripts/SchoolClosureManager/SchoolClosureManager.py", line 210, in <module>
    runnable.run()
  File "/var/scripts/SchoolClosureManager/SchoolClosureManager.py", line 18, in run
    reporter = SchoolClosureReporter(xml.name)
  File "/var/scripts/SchoolClosureManager/SchoolClosureManager.py", line 40, in __init__
    document = objectify.fromstring(xml, parser)
  File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 1826, in lxml.objectify.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:18625)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2532, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:48634)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1536, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72156)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.
```

I have found this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/683069 that basically says that it was a bug and has been `Fixed in trunk rev. 79947`

Am I able to just update the `lxml` dist-package?

I'm currently running python2.6.5 on Ubuntu 8.04.

Comment: I disagree with those who vote to close this question because "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**". `lxml` seems like a programming tool to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked with Ubuntu 11.10; I'm not sure if it will work with Ubuntu 8.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
```

If you are using `virtualenv` (which I recommend for safety and flexibility):

```
# with your virtual environment activated
pip install --upgrade lxml
pip install cssselect   # cssselect has been spun-off into its own project
```

If not using `virtualenv`, you could uninstall the Ubuntu package lxml:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-lxml
```

and then install the latest `lxml` package system-wide with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade lxml
sudo pip install cssselect
```

---

*Updated to show the method of installation found per a discussion in the comments. Note that this did not solve the `ValueError` exception the OP was seeing; it only updated the version of lxml.*

Note that the `pip` executable is a Python script, run by a certain installation of Python. It might be possible to use a single `pip` with many Python installations, but since hard drive space is relatively cheap, most people install one `pip` executable for each Python installation.

So if you have multiple Python installations on your system, it is important to use the `pip` executable which is linked to your target Python executable.

In the OP's case

```
import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

returned

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.6
```

Since a `/usr/local/bin/pip` existed,

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install --upgrade lxml
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install cssselect
```

were the appropriate commands.

---

To test which version of lxml you are using:

```
In [38]: import lxml.etree as ET

In [44]: ET.__version__
Out[44]: u'3.2.0'

In [45]: ET.LIBXML_COMPILED_VERSION
Out[46]: (2, 7, 8)

In [47]: ET.LIBXSLT_COMPILED_VERSION
Out[48]: (1, 1, 26)
```

---

To check the location of the module you are using:

```
In [57]: import lxml.etree as ET

In [58]: ET
Out[58]: <module 'lxml.etree' from '/home/unutbu/.virtualenvs/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so'>
```

Comment: Am I able to tell which version of lxml my python script is running? The link I provided above shows ` /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so` which makes me think I'm using something that's included with Python.

Comment: When I run `sudo apt-get remove lxml` I get the error `Couldn't find package lxml`. Is `lxml` the same as `libxml2`?

Comment: Oops -- the package is called `python-lxml`, not `lxml`. `libxml2` is a dependency used by `python-lxml`.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get remove python-lxml`.

This is what was returned:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-lxml is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: These are the only packages I have installed with "xml" in the name `libxml-parser-perl,    
libxml2,    
libxml2-dev,     
libxml2-utils,     
xml-core`

Comment: I had assumed you were using the python-lxml package. It appears I was entirely wrong about that. Did you install `lxml` yourself? If so, just skip the `sudo apt-get remove python-lxml` and try upgrading to a new version with `sudo pip install ...`.

Comment: It may be helpful to check where your current installation of lxml is installed. I've added some commands in the post above to show how to find out the location of `etree.so` on your system. By default I think `sudo pip install` will install packages to `/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages`. If your current installation is located elsewhere, you'll have to make sure your `sys.path` leads Python to select the right installation when you `import lxml`. We can talk about that more if it proves to be a problem...

Comment: I ran the `sudo pip install --upgrade lxml` and when I run `pip freeze` it shows that I `lxml==3.2.4`. If I use the method you mentioned above for finding the version of lxml. I get ` ET.__version__
u'2.2.6'` So I think I'm updating or modifying the wrong install of lxml.

Comment: I'm getting `<module 'lxml.etree' from '/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.2.6-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/lxml/etree.so'>` for my output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42674/discussion-between-unutbu-and-bigmike7801)

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem with the `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.` but it was the answer to the question I was asking.